# Displaying Related Information From DropDown into a table data cell element. (From SQL Database)

Tags: javascript, php, html, sql

So, I can populate the dropdown with information from the database, however I what I need to be done is when I click on an option in the dropdown, it should display the description of that selected option (Item) in a table data cell element. It does not want to show anything in the table data when the user selects an option.

This works perfectly fine from a dropdown to a textbox (Not inside of the table).

HTML / PHP

```css
          <script>
         var mySelect = document.getElementById("pull_data");
         mySelect.addEventListener("change", function() {
         var myOptionFour = mySelect.options[mySelect.selectedIndex].getAttribute("data-description");
            document.getElementsById('details').value = myOptionFour;
         
         });
         
         </script>
```

```html
 <table class="inventory">
               <thead>
                  <th>
                     <span>
                        <h2>Service Date</h2>
                     </span>
                  </th>
                  <th>
                     <span>
                        <h2>Item</h2>
                     </span>
                  </th>
                  <th>
                     <span>
                        <h2>Description</h2>
                     </span>
                  </th>
                  <th>
                     <span>
                        <h2>Rate</h2>
                     </span>
                  </th>
                  <th>
                     <span>
                        <h2>Quantity</h2>
                     </span>
                  </th>
                  <th>
                     <span>
                        <h2>Subtotal</h2>
                     </span>
                  </th>
               </thead>
               <tbody>
                  <tr>
                     <!------ Service Date -------->
                     <td>
                        <a class="cut">-</a><span contenteditable></span>           
                     </td>
                     <!------ Item -------->
                     <td>
                        <span contenteditable>
                           <div class="productSelect">
                              <select name="pull_data" id="pull_data">
                                 <option value="" disabled selected>Click to See Products</option>
                                 <?php
                                    $records = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM products");
                                        while($data = mysqli_fetch_array($records))
                                                        {
                                      
                                     echo '<option value="'.$data['name'].'" data-description="' . $data['description'].'">' . $data['name'] . '</option>';
                                        }
                                    ?>
                              </select>
                           </div>
                        </span>
                     </td>
                     <!------ Description -------->
                     <td>
                        <span id="details" name="details" contenteditable></span>
                     </td>
```

Comment: `document.getElementsByTagName('details')[2].value = myOptionFour;` - you do not appear to have any elements with the tag name `details` anywhere.

Comment: (And even if you did - `.value` only works for form fields. For "normal" HTML elements containing text, you'd want to either set `.innerText` or `.innerHTML`)

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of things that are fuzzy with your question and you should post more detailed information. But here is an example of what you might be looking for:

```
   



var mySelect = document.getElementById("pull_data");

    var t = mySelect.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.querySelectorAll(":scope > td[data-name='details']")[0].children[0];
    
    mySelect.addEventListener("change", function () {
        var myOption = mySelect.options[mySelect.selectedIndex].getAttribute("data-email"); // None existing
        //document.getElementById('mail').value = myOption; // None existing
        var myOptionTwo = mySelect.options[mySelect.selectedIndex].getAttribute("data-street"); // None existing
        //document.getElementById('street').value = myOptionTwo; // None existing
        var myOptionThree = mySelect.options[mySelect.selectedIndex].getAttribute("data-rate"); // None existing
        //document.getElementById('price').value = myOptionThree; // None existing
        var myOptionFour = mySelect.options[mySelect.selectedIndex].getAttribute("data-description");
        // document.('details')[2].value = myOptionFour;

        t.innerHTML = myOptionFour;

    });
<table class="inventory">
    <thead>
        <th>
            <span>
                <h2>Service Date</h2>
            </span>
        </th>
        <th>
            <span>
                <h2>Item</h2>
            </span>
        </th>
        <th>
            <span>
                <h2>Description</h2>
            </span>
        </th>
        <th>
            <span>
                <h2>Rate</h2>
            </span>
        </th>
        <th>
            <span>
                <h2>Quantity</h2>
            </span>
        </th>
        <th>
            <span>
                <h2>Subtotal</h2>
            </span>
        </th>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="table_body">
        <tr>
            <!------ Service Date -------->
            <td>
                <a class="cut">-</a><span contenteditable></span>
            </td>
            <!------ Item -------->
            <td>
                <span contenteditable>
                    <div class="productSelect">
                        <select name="pull_data" id="pull_data">
                            <option value="" disabled selected>Click to See Products</option>
                            <?php

                                $datas = array(
                                    array(
                                        "name"=>"val1",
                                        "description"=>"dis is val1",
                                    ),
                                    array(
                                        "name"=>"val2",
                                        "description"=>"dis is val2",
                                    ),
                                    array(
                                        "name"=>"val3",
                                        "description"=>"dis is val3",
                                    ),
                                );

                                    foreach ($datas as $key => $data) {
                                        echo '<option value="'.$data['name'].'" data-description="' . $data['description'].'">' . $data['name'] . '</option>';
                                    }
                                ?>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                </span>
            </td>
            <!------ Description -------->
            <td data-name="details">
                <span contenteditable></span>
            </td>
</table>




--------
Now, if this does not work then please complement your question with at least the following information: the entire code (not missing any closing HTML-tags), the database information that you use to import the information into the table, a clear question in plain english and clear description of what you are striving to achieve and lastly purge the JS-code you submitted from code that is not relevant to the HTML you submitted.
```